# Delete certain blanks

Tags: java, string

How to change the textstring

```
New York, Apple Tree, Banana , Marc Polo
```

to

```
New York,Apple Tree,Banana,Marc Polo
```

I have no idea about how to delete certain blanks which is not between two words.

Any help?

Comment: You simply want to remove all blanks that's next to a `,` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `replaceAll` with a regular expression that matches a comma and the surrounding whitespaces and replaces it with just the comma:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s*,\\s*", ",");
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/MXsYM)

Note: This won't remove spaces at the beginning or end of the line. To remove those too you *could* modify the regular expression, but simpler is to just call [`String.Trim`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) afterwards.

Comment: Can you explain why the text isn't replaced? I thought `\s*` meant _every alphabetic character, for 0 or more times_.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: No, `\s` means "whitespace". Perhaps you were thinking of `\w` which matches a "word character" which is `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`?

Answer (score 4):

You can either replace (commas surrounded by whitespace) with just commas, or Split on commas, then join the trimmed results.